# Sifteo: how to create a file.txt with LUA script?

Tags: scripting, lua, sifteo

i'm trying to create a Sifteo game able to detect accelerometer data and write them on a file.txt;
I know that several methods exist that allow to visualize data on the shell (but it need to connect the base on the pc) or storing them in a StoredObject, but i'd like to create a text file.
In the documentation of sifteo sdk  I found something about script lua.
I didn't understand it, Can you help me???

Thanks

Comment: `assert(assert(io.open('file.txt', 'w')):write(file_content))`

Comment: please post the text from SDK docs that you do not understand

Comment: Hi, here the information I found on scripting htt://developers.sifteo.com/docs/SifteoSDK/0.9.8/scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply asking for how to make a .txt file in a lua script it should be something like

```
file = io.open("FileName.txt","w")
file:write("Information")
file:close()
```

If you're new to lua you can also insert information from a variable or a table by replacing it with the string "Information".

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks but I'm not asking about lua script. I'm simply interesting to know how to write accelerometer data of a cube in a file.txt